# Looping over a slice copy of a list

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the difference between **looping over a list** and **looping over a "slice" copy of a list**.

So, for example, in the following list, the element whose length is greater than 6 is appended to the beginning of the list:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'blahblah']

for word in words[:]:
    if len(word) > 6:
        words.insert(0, word)

print(words)

words = ['blahblah', 'cat', 'window', 'blahblah']
```

I, then, run the following to see why it is not the correct way of doing it, but my interpreter freezes and I have to exit. Why does this happen? I am simply appending something to the start of my list which is allowed since lists are mutable...

```
for word in words:
    if len(word) > 6:
        words.insert(0, word)
```

Could someone please help me understand why this last bit stops my program?

Comment: Its because you are modifying and adding to the list as you loop through it. Its not good practice to modify something you are looping through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list `words` has three elements. The copy of `words` also does. You iterate over the copy, insert something in `words` if the current element is longer than 6 characters, and are done.

Now let's see what happens when you iterate over `words` directly:

The first two iteration steps are fine, because the condition is False. But since `len('blahblah') > 6`, you are now inserting `'blahblah'` at the beginning of the list. Now the list looks like this:

`['blahblah', 'cat', 'window', 'blahblah']`

You've just seen the third element, so now the loop continues and looks at the fourth element, but because you inserted something at the beginning of the list the rest of the list shifted and the new fourth element is `'blahblah'` again. `blahblah` is still longer than 6 characters, you insert it again in the beginning and are stuck in an infinite loop:

```
['cat', 'window', 'blahblah']
   ^
['cat', 'window', 'blahblah']
            ^
['cat', 'window', 'blahblah']
                       ^
['blahblah', 'cat', 'window', 'blahblah']
                                   ^
['blahblah', 'blahblah', 'cat', 'window', 'blahblah']
                                               ^
...
```

Comment: When I write ```print words[:]``` in loop, I see it growing - it is true for ```print words``` also. Fail to understand why it does not go into infinite loop for 1st case.

Comment: If you write `print words[:]` in the loop, it is making a new copy every time, but the copy you iterate over doesn't change. You can see that by writing `copy = words[:]` before the loop, iterating over `copy` and printing `copy` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your first approach, you are performing a shallow copy of your list `words`, iterating over it and appending long words to the list `words`. So you iterate over a fixed list, and extend a different list.

With your last approach, the list `words` grows with each iteration, so you are in an endless loop as you are looping over it and it keeps growing.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing `words[:]`, you are iterating over the copy of list, whereas with `words`, you are iterating over the original copy of list.

In the case `II`, your interpreter is freezing because when you are at the last index, the condition is satisfied and you insert the item at the beginning of the list. Now, there is one more index which is required to be iterated by the loop. Again, the condition satisfies and it keeps on going like this resulting in an infinite loop.

Where as that is not the case with `words[:]`, as the list in which you are appending and the one on which you are iterating are different.

Answer (score 1):

The following loop

```
for word in words:
    // do something
```

is roughly equivalent to the following one (when `words` is a list and not another kind of `iterable`):

```
i = 0
while i != len(words):
    word = words[i]
    // do something (assuming no 'continue' here)
    i += 1
```

Therefore, when while looping you insert something into your list *before the current position*, then during the next iteration you end up handling the same element as for the previous iteration. In your case this results in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

`words[:]` means a new copy of the `words` and length is fixed. So you are iterating over a fixed list.

But in the second situation, iterating over and extending the same list which makes it infinity.

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'blahblah']
new_words = [_ for _ in words if len(_) > 6]
print(new_words)
```

Comment: Not the correct answer because, the user is not asking, how should he do it, rather, why the method he is following is failing.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to see what exactly happens in the background of inserting into the list (words) vs slice copy (words[:]), you can change/tab the print to see the infinite loop, as the infinite loop cannot be seen in its original location in the script:

```
for w in words:  
if len(w) > 6:
    words.insert(0, w) 
print(words) #prints after each insert, let you see the infinite loop
```